# After login I want to refresh the NavBar, is rendering only when I refresh the page but not on Navigate

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

```
function App() {
  const [token, setToken] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    const auth = localStorage.getItem('auth_token');
    setToken(auth);
  }, [token]);

  return (
    <div>
      <FullNavBar />
      <Routes>
        <Route path='/login' element={<Login />}></Route>
        <Route path='/register' element={<Register />}></Route>
        <Route path='/forgot_password' element={<ForgotPassword />}></Route>
        <Route element={<ProtectedRoutes />}>
          <Route path='/home' element={<Home />}></Route>
          <Route path='/active_lottery' element={<Activelottery />}></Route>
        </Route>
      </Routes>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Protected Routes:

```
import { Navigate, Outlet } from 'react-router';

const authorization = () => {
  const token = localStorage.getItem('auth_token');
  return token ? true : false;
};

const ProtectedRoutes = () => {
  const isAuth = authorization();
  return isAuth ? <Outlet /> : <Navigate to='/login' />;
};

export default ProtectedRoutes;
```

How can I make that navbar to render after changing the page?
After I'm trying to log in I'm redirected to the homepage but I still have the previous NavBar,is re-rendering after I'm refreshing the page.
Login redirect:

```
const onSubmitHandler = async (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  await axios
    .post(
      'url/dev/user/login',
      loginForm,
    )
    .then((response) => {
      localStorage.setItem(
        'auth_token',
        response.data.AuthenticationResult.AccessToken,
      );
      toast.success('Your in now');
      setTimeout(() => {
        navigate('/home');
      }, 1000);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
      toast.error(err.response.data.message);
    });
};
```

and in the fullNavBar component I want to update the pages from navBar.

```
export default function FullNavBar() {
  const [menuOpen, setMenuOpen] = useState(false);
  const [auth, setAuth] = useState(false);

  const token = localStorage.getItem('auth_token');

  useEffect(() => {
    if (token) {
      console.log(token);
      setAuth(true);
    }
  }, [auth]);

  return (
    <div className="bg-gradient-to-r from-yellow-400 to-yellow-500">
      <Navbar token={auth} menuOpen={menuOpen} setMenuOpen={setMenuOpen} />
      {menuOpen && <MobileMenu>{navLinks(auth)}</MobileMenu>}
    </div>
  );
}

const navLinks = token => {
  let pages = ['About', 'Contact', 'Login'];

  if (token) {
    pages = ['Buy', 'Tickets', 'History', 'Profile'];
  }

  return pages.map(page =>
    page === 'Profile' ? (
      <button key={page} className="inline-block">
        {' '}
        <img
          className="rounded-full w-11 h-11"
          src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQhumf_G7azRo-qCcnB533PPwZx386EK1cozzMAMEtW3A&s"
        ></img>
      </button>
    ) : page === 'Tickets' ? (
      <a
        key={page}
        className="no-underline text-gray-800 font-semibold hover:text-gray-500 relative bottom-4"
        href={`${page.toLowerCase()}`}
      >
        100 {page}
      </a>
    ) : (
      <a
        key={page}
        className="no-underline text-gray-800 font-semibold hover:text-gray-500 relative bottom-4"
        href={`${page.toLowerCase()}`}
      >
        {page}
      </a>
    ),
  );
};
```

everything is working fine after I'm refreshing the page but when it's redirected from login to home the navBar component isn't called

Comment: Please edit the post to include ***all*** relevant code you are working with and have an issue using. What isn't updating in the `FullNavBar ` component that it needs to be rerendered? See [mcve].

Comment: If you are still unable to get it to work, you can post the code for your login page as well. After logging in, you should also set the token of your app component via react context so that the entire app gets re-rendered(your navbar as well) because react-navigation does not cause re-render of the page unless you do it yourself. Let me know if you need help with how to use react context in your app.

Comment: Yes, I need some help.

Comment: After you redirect the user, the `FullNavBar` component won't be updated because nothing has changed in the component. I suggest using a context with setters and getters for the auth token. This way, everything will be updated properly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is that the code is trying to use localStorage actively as the source of truth. It is only to be used for longer-term storage of your React state. Use the `token` state in `App` as the active source of truth and pass the `token` state and state updater function down as props to the relevant components that care.

Example:

App

Use a state initializer function to set/provide the initial `token` state from localStorage. Use the `useEffect` hook to persist `token` state changes to localStorage.

```
function App() {
  const [token, setToken] = useState(() => {
    // Initialize from localStorage
    return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('auth_token'));
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    // Persist state changes to localStorage
    localStorage.setItem('auth_token', JSON.stringify(token));
  }, [token]);

  return (
    <div>
      <FullNavBar token={token} /> // <-- pass token as prop
      <Routes>
        <Route
          path='/login'
          element={<Login setToken={setToken} />} // <-- pass state updater function
        />
        <Route path='/register' element={<Register />} />
        <Route path='/forgot_password' element={<ForgotPassword />} />
        <Route
          element={<ProtectedRoutes isAuth={!!token} />} // <-- pass isAuth prop
        >
          <Route path='/home' element={<Home />} />
          <Route path='/active_lottery' element={<Activelottery />} />
        </Route>
      </Routes>
    </div>
  );
}
```

ProtectedRoutes

```
import { Navigate, Outlet } from 'react-router';

const ProtectedRoutes = ({ isAuth }) => {
  return isAuth ? <Outlet /> : <Navigate to='/login' replace />;
};

export default ProtectedRoutes;
```

Login

Destructure and access the passed `setToken` callback and call it and pass the new token value to update the state in `App`.

```
const Login = ({ setToken }) = { // <-- access state updater function
  ...

  const onSubmitHandler = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    await axios
      .post('url/dev/user/login', loginForm)
      .then((response) => {
        setToken(response.data.AuthenticationResult.AccessToken); // <-- save token to state
        toast.success('You're in now');
        setTimeout(() => {
          navigate('/home');
        }, 1000);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
        toast.error(err.response.data.message);
      });
  };

  ...
};
```

FullNavBar

Access the passed `token` prop. Instead of using the `token` to set some local `auth` state just consume the token directly.

```
export default function FullNavBar({ token }) { // <-- access token prop
  const [menuOpen, setMenuOpen] = useState(false);

  return (
    <div className="bg-gradient-to-r from-yellow-400 to-yellow-500">
      <Navbar
        token={token} // <-- pass to Navbar
        menuOpen={menuOpen}
        setMenuOpen={setMenuOpen}
      />
      {menuOpen && (
        <MobileMenu>
          {navLinks(token)} // <-- pass to navLinks utility
        </MobileMenu>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}

const navLinks = token => {
  let pages = ['About', 'Contact', 'Login'];

  if (token) {
    pages = ['Buy', 'Tickets', 'History', 'Profile'];
  }

  return pages.map(page =>
    ....,
  );
};
```